# Get last four characters from a string

Tags: macos, command-line, sed, grep, cut

I am trying to parse the last 4 characters of Mac serial numbers from terminal. I can grab the serial with this command:

`serial=$(ioreg -l |grep "IOPlatformSerialNumber"|cut -d ""="" -f 2|sed -e s/[^[:alnum:]]//g)`

but I need to output just the last 4 characters.

Comment: What is the output of `ioreg -l`? Because there is probably a more straight forward way to do this without so many pipes.

Comment: What do you think `cut -d ""=""` means? And as fedorqui mentions, there certainly is a much better approach!

Comment: To provide context for future readers: There are 2 distinct ways to answer this question: (a) extract the last 4 chars. from a shell variable's value (in which case the command that was used to fill this variable originally is irrelevant), or (b) improve the command that assigns to the shell variable so as to _directly_ return only its last 4 characters, without the need for later extraction. Existing answers cover both approaches, with (b) answers initially hampered by not knowing `ioreg`'s output format; here's an example line: `|   "IOPlatformSerialNumber" = "A02UV13KDNMJ"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [a shell parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479461/45375) to extract the last 4 characters *after* the fact works, but you could do it all in one step:

```
ioreg -k IOPlatformSerialNumber | sed -En 's/^.*"IOPlatformSerialNumber".*(.{4})"$/\1/p'
```

- `ioreg -k IOPlatformSerialNumber` returns much fewer lines than `ioreg -l`, so it speeds up the operation considerably (about 80% faster on my machine).
- The `sed` command matches the entire line of interest, and replaces it with the last 4 characters before the `"` that ends the line; i.e., it returns the last 4 chars. of the value.

Note: The `ioreg` output line of interest looks something like this:

```
    |   "IOPlatformSerialNumber" = "A02UV13KDNMJ"
```

---

As for your original command: `cut -d ""=""` is the same as `cut -d =` - the shell simply removes the empty strings around the `=` before `cut` sees the value. Note that `cut` only accepts a *single* delimiter char.

Comment: What would be the best way to modify this to convert all characters to lowercase as well?

Comment: @Brian: append `| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` to the command.

Answer (score 3):

Found it in a linux forum `echo ${serial:(-4)}`

Comment: That assumes you have a variable named `serial` populated by your previously posted chain of commands but you don't need those and so you don't need this.

Comment: This is indeed simplest if your value is already stored in a variable; slightly simpler and prettier alternative: `${serial: -4}` (note the required space before `-`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do: `grep -Eo '.{4}$' <<< "$serial"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the output of `ioreg -l` looks like, but it looks to me that you are using so many pipes to do something that `awk` alone could handle:

```
    use = as field separator
    vvv
awk -F= '/IOPlatformSerialNumber/ {      #match lines containing IOPlatform...
           gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, "", $2)  # replace all non alpha chars from 2nd field
           print substr($2, length($2)-3, length($2))   # print last 4 characters
         }'
```

<strike>Or even `sed` (a bit ugly one since the repetition of command): catch the first 4 alphanumeric characters occuring after the first `=`:</strike>

```
sed -rn '/IOPlatformSerialNumber/{
           s/^[^=]*=[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9])[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9])[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9])[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9]).*$/\1\2\3\4/;p
         }'
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
aaa
bbIOPlatformSerialNumber=A_+23B/44C//55=ttt
IOPlatformSerialNumber=A_+23B/44C55=ttt
asdfasd
```

The last 4 alphanumeric characters between the 1st and 2nd `=` are `4C55`:

```
$ awk -F= '/IOPlatformSerialNumber/ {gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, "", $2); print substr($2, length($2)-3, length($2))}' a
4C55
4C55
```

Answer (score 0):

Without you posting some sample output of `ioreg -l` this is untested and a guess but it looks like all you need is something like:

```
ioreg -l | sed -r -n 's/IOPlatformSerialNumber=[[:alnum:]]+([[:alnum:]]{4})/\1/'
```

Comment: You must use `sed -E` rather than `sed -r` on OSX, and you're missing the `s` command, but otherwise this strikes me as the best approach in principle (it doesn't match the output format, however).

Comment: Mmmm what if the value after the first `=` is something like `A_+23B/44C5//5` (my example)? You have to get the last 4 alphanumeric characters, where these can have interleaved non alphanumeric chars. I think this is not checked currently.

Comment: @mklement0 added the `s`, thanks. I guess if you're on OSX you'll know what to do with `-r` vs `-E` or ask about it.

Comment: @fedorqui given that all we have to go on so far is the OPs attempt at a script which does NOT work, there are many ways in which any of the answers given so far might not work, it's just not worth guessing at anything more than the approach until the OP provides some sample input and expected output. I don't think the OPs listening any more anyway - I think he's happy with his goofy chain of pipes...